# PHP MySQL prepared-statement prepare() fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

the following returns false and i don't know how to find out what exactly is wrong.

```
$stmt = $dbo->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions ('id', 'time') VALUES ('',?)")) // returns false
{
}
```

i have another statement which does an select open at that time. is it a problem to have more than one statements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you verified that you are connecting to the database successfully?

```
/* check connection */
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

As far as figuring out what's wrong with your prepared statement, you should be able to display $stmt->error, which will return a string description of the latest statement error, and $dbo->error, which will return the latest mysqli error.

```
printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
```

Comment: thanks it gives me: DB Error: prepare Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: The following SO questions may be of use to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632075/mysqli-giving-commands-out-of-sync-error-why

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614671/commands-out-of-sync-you-cant-run-this-command-now1

Answer (score 0):

You don't want single quotes around your table names. It should look like this:

```
$stmt = $dbo->stmt_init();
if($stmt->prepare("INSERT INTO transactions (id, time) VALUES ('', ?)")) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check whether those columns are properly entered... as i was getting same error coz i mentioned non existing column name in the query..