# Adding 2 SELECT queries in mysqli/php code is causing errors

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a working php/mysqli code below where it inserts questions and answers successfully:

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent) 
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";



        $sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');

            if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    } else{

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){      


$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value) {
$answer = $value;


        $insert->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $id, $_POST['questionText'][$i]);

        $insert->execute();

        if ($insert->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

       $lastID = $insert->insert_id;

       $insert->close();

        foreach($value as $answer) {

         $answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

      if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }  

    $insertanswer->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $lastID, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
          // Handle query error here
        }

        $insertanswer->close();

}
}

}

}
```

But a trouble I have been having even before getting the above code to work is that I have 2 additional SELECT queries which I need include in the code above. The queries are known as `$replystmt` and `$optionstmt`. The problem though is that if I include those queries in the php/mysqli code above, I keep receiving these errors:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt::execute(): (HY000/2014): Commands out of sync;
>   you can't run this command now in /insertQuestion.php on line 236 241:
>
> Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now Fatal error:
>   Cannot break/continue 2 levels in /insertQuestion.php on line 242

Now the full code is below, my question is that what do I need to change in my code in order for the errors to be removed and the code to work?

Below is the full php/mysqli code:

```
$replyquery = "SELECT ReplyId FROM Reply WHERE (ReplyType = ?)";

if (!$replystmt = $mysqli->prepare($replyquery)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

$optionquery = "SELECT OptionId FROM Option_Table WHERE (OptionType = ?)";

if (!$optionstmt = $mysqli->prepare($optionquery)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

// Prepare your statements ahead of time
$questionsql = "INSERT INTO Question (SessionId, QuestionId, QuestionContent, NoofAnswers, ReplyId, QuestionMarks, OptionId) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($questionsql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}

$answersql = "INSERT INTO Answer (SessionId, QuestionId, Answer) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
if (!$insertanswer = $mysqli->prepare($answersql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
echo __LINE__.': '.$mysqli->error;
}



//make sure both prepared statements succeeded before proceeding
if( $insert && $insertanswer)
{
$sessid =  $_SESSION['id'] . ($_SESSION['initial_count'] > 1 ? $_SESSION['sessionCount'] : '');
$c = count($_POST['numQuestion']);

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ )
{

$selected_option = "A-C"; 
$selected_reply = "Single"; 


// Bind parameter for statement
$optionstmt->bind_param("s", $selected_option);

// Execute the statement
$optionstmt->execute();

if ($optionstmt->errno) 
{
// Handle query error here
echo __LINE__.': '.$optionstmt->error;
break 1;
}

// This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
// variables before calling fetch()
$optionstmt->bind_result($optionid);

// This populates $optionid
$optionstmt->fetch();




// Bind parameter for statement
$replystmt->bind_param("s", $selected_reply);

// Execute the statement
$replystmt->execute(); //Line 236

if ($replystmt->errno) 
{
// Handle query error here
echo __LINE__.': '.$replystmt->error; //Line 241
break 2;
}

// This is what matters. With MySQLi you have to bind result fields to
// variables before calling fetch()
$replystmt->bind_result($replyid);

// This populates $optionid
$replystmt->fetch(); 

$insert->bind_param("sisiiii", $sessid, $_POST['numQuestion'][$i], $_POST['questionText'][$i],
$_POST['numberAnswer'][$i], $replyid, $_POST['textWeight'][$i],
$optionid);

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) 
{
// Handle query error here
echo __LINE__.': '.$insert->error;
break 3;
}
}

$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value) 
{
$answer = $value;

$lastID = $id;



foreach($value as $answer) 
{
$insertanswer->bind_param("sis", $sessid, $lastID, $answer);

$insertanswer->execute();

if ($insertanswer->errno) {
// Handle query error here
echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
break 4;
}
}
}


//close your statements at the end


$insertanswer->close();
$insert->close();
$replystmt->close(); 
$optionstmt->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two different problems happening here. Firstly, the `Commands out of sync` warning is happening because you are trying to initiate new queries before actually finishing the previous ones. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632320/626682) for more information about that. Basically, you have to close each of the queries you are preparing before preparing the next one.

As for the `Cannot break/continue` error, that is happening because you are calling `break 2` when you are only 1 level deep. The optional number after `break` (or `continue`) is the number of 'levels' to break out of.

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    // 1 level
    for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++){
        // 2 levels

        break;      // Break of the $j loop
        break 1;    // Equivalent to above

        break 2;    // Break out of both the $j and $i loops

        break 3;    // Causes an error - there is no third level
    }
}
```

Of course, in that example it would never reach the other `break`s after hitting the first one, but it should illustrate the concept. See also [the documentation for `break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php).