# MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've got this test table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
    `id` INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
```

inserting using either of these three

```sql
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (NULL);
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`) VALUES (0);
INSERT INTO `test` () VALUES ();
```

and issuing

```sql
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

but the query always results in `0`.

PHP's `mysql_insert_id` and `PDO::lastInsertId()` yield no result either.

I've been toying with this whole day and can't get it to work. Ideas?

Comment: I just tried it with mysql v5.5.25 and it worked fine.

Comment: does this happen when you run the queries directly from a mySQL command line? If it's only happening when you run the queries through PHP, it might be a connection issue.

Comment: I am running it directly in the command line. I have the same MySQL version as you do. Do I have to issue the commands in one block as Zubin suggests?

Comment: the `;` between them makes them separates them.  Putting them together on one line makes no difference.

Comment: That's what I thought but as Zubin suggested, when I put then in one block `LAST_INSERT_ID()` work, but when they're separated, it still results in `0`. No idea what's going on.

Comment: here's the ref for last_insert_id() http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Comment: I've read that but still of no help to me.

Comment: I'm wondering if there is something in your config that has turned off insert id tracking.

Comment: How to find out/set it on? Though I doubt that's the case. I've tried it not only on local, but on remote server as well. With no success.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21145/discussion-between-dnagirl-and-davidl)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem seemed to be in MySQL's phpmyadmin config file `PersistentConnections` set to `FALSE` which resulted in a new `CONNECTION_ID` every time a query was issued - therefore rendering `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` ineffective.

more info in the subsequent topic [Every query creates a new CONNECTION_ID()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13882333/every-query-creates-a-new-connection-id)

Also thanks [dnagirl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128245/dnagirl) for help

Answer (score 21):

Just my 50 cents for this issue, I simply noticed that you won't get a `LAST_INSERT_ID` greater than `0` if your table has no `AUTO_INCREMENT` set to an index.

I wasted about half hour on this. Turns out I keep getting a `LAST_INSERT_ID()` of `0`, which for this table is actually ok.

Comment: My table's id is auto increment and it's primary key. Still getting 0

Comment: same here, my table's id is alsi set to auto increment and it's a primary key. but i still get 0

Answer (score 12):

you have to combine

```
INSERT INTO test (title) VALUES ('test');SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Then you will get the last insert id

Comment: I see. But is then possible to set up a `MySQL` trigger that fires after table test `INSERT` and creates a row in a junction table using a `last_insert_id()` from the test table?

Comment: I think it is also possible, please have a try

Comment: Trigger `INSERT INTO tasks_tags (id_task,id_tag) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),'1')` fails at FK because the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in the trigger already results in `0`

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't always work out of the box: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3632320/997940 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/28527704/997940

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. `mysql_insert_id()` or `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returned 0 when requested inside a PHP function with an **INSERT query**.

I sorted the issue by requesting the value of `mysql_insert_id()` from a separate PHP function called right after the function that **INSERT query**.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same issues but I have resolved this by creating a transaction.

```
$db->begin();
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'test' VALUES('test')";

if ($db->query($sql))
{
    $id = $db->last_insert_id('test');
    $db->commit();
    return $id;
}
else{
    $db->rollback();
    return -1;
}
```

I had tried

```
return $db->last_insert_id('test');
```

after the "commit" but that always returned "0"

hope that can help you

Answer (score -2):

it work perfectly...try it...

```
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `test` (`title`) VALUES ('test')");
    if ($result) {
        $id = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id = $id") or die(mysql_error());
        // return user details
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            return mysql_fetch_array($result);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```