# Every query creates a new CONNECTION_ID()

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Each and every SQL query I issue to my `MySQL` server creates a new (increments) `CONNECTION_ID()`. This happens both on my local as well as on my shared remote server.

Is this the reason behind `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `ROW_COUNT()` resulting in `0`? How to address this issue?

Originally in [MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0)

Comment: MySQL server doesn't have a command line.  There is a separate command-line client utility that can connect to a MySQL server.  Is that what you're referring to?  If so, have you set a non-default [`connect_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_connect_timeout)?

Comment: My bad. I mean't a simple SQL query box of my `phpmyadmin`. Let me check the timeout.

Comment: do remember that last_insert_id only works on auto incremented fields, not manually given..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, [`PersistentConnections`](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config#PersistentConnections) are disabled in phpMyAdmin.

> Is this the reason behind `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `ROW_COUNT()` resulting in `0`?

Yes.

> How to address this issue?

Enable persistent connections:

```php
$cfg['PersistentConnections'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: Solved `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, `ROW_COUNT()` still `0` after `INSERT`. Going to further test it

Comment: Anyway, when a phpmyadmin config file is not available (on remote shared) there is no way to get a `last_id` other than to do a `SELECT` on a table?