# How to handle auto_increment in master and transaction table?

Tags: mysql

I'd like to know the right and proper practice to handle auto_increment in this table structure problem. Let's say I have these table:

StudentMaster

```
ID        auto_increment
name      varchar(100)
Status    int(11)
```

StudentDetail

```
ID         varchar(10)
examID     varchar(20)
examDate   date
```

When I insert a data to StudentMaster and StudentDetail in one action, how to make the `ID` in StudentDetail has the same value with StudentMaster? Because in the new form, there is no textbox containing ID to be inputted.

Data example:

```
ID     Name     Status
1      Roy          1
2      Nicole       2

ID    examID       examDate
1         A1     2017-05-15
1         A2     2017-05-15
1         A5     2017-05-17
2         A2     2017-05-15
1         A3     2017-05-16
```

P.S: I am in the database structure phase. The PHP form is not created yet.

Comment: First off, the ID in StudentDetail should also be INT.  
Usually you insert into the StudentMaster first, get the ID value and use that to insert all the other data in StudentDetail.

Comment: How? in the form there is no textbox for ID. Because it's auto_increment. The data that user need to input for StudentMaster is just name and status.

Comment: Yes, but in StudentDetail you have varchar(10) as ID, make this an INT instead. The two inserts has to be made in the application code. There is also a good answer on how to get the latest added id here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501464/how-to-get-the-id-of-inserted-row-in-mysql

Comment: `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` returns 0 ??

Comment: Did you insert a row in StudentMaster before running last_insert_id()?

Comment: yes. I insert the data directly

Comment: Look at this post. Dont know what interface you use though. But you seem to need to do the last_insert_id in the same connection as your insert statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0