# MySQL sequence doesn't return LAST_INSERT_ID

Tags: mysql

I am following [mysql docs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32505813/5275087) to create a sequence for a table

Main table:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id   INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Sequence table:

```
CREATE TABLE person_sequence (
    id INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO person_sequence VALUES (0);
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER person_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON person
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.id is null THEN
        UPDATE person_sequence SET id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id+1);
        SET new.id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
    END IF;
END;
```

When I try to insert into the main table:

```
INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('John');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

The insert with sequence works fine. but the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` returns `0`

Limitation:
I can't modify the insert query(to first call the sequence and then insert with id provided in the insert query).

Why don't I use an `AUTO_INCREMENT` id for the main table?
part of data is replicated from another database which has its own sequence and id range.

**Update**

Also doesn't work if I insert into the sequence table. changes:

```
CREATE TABLE person_sequence (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
);

CREATE TRIGGER person_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON person
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF new.id is null THEN
        insert into person_sequence (id) values (null);
        SET new.id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: You have NOT done an INSERT prior to using the `LAST_INSERT_ID()` because this is a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger  :) and it should probably have been coded as `LAST_INSERT_ID()+1` anyway

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13880267/mysql-last-insert-id-returns-0  , still, if you want the last Id you can use " SELECT id FROM person ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 "