# Proper way to bind an array to prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This has probably been asked a handful of times already, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to bind an array to a mysqli prepared statement.

What I'm trying to do is query for a list of user id's in a message thread, and then insert into the messages table so the user can be notified of a new message reply.

This is what I've tried:

```
//now check which users are in the message thread
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT user_id_2
FROM uc_user_messages
WHERE thread_id =  ?");
$stmt2->bind_param("i", $this->thread_id_clean);
$stmt2->bind_result($user_2_id);
$stmt2->execute();

$stmt3 = $mysqli->prepare("
INSERT INTO `users`.`uc_user_messages`(
    `id` ,
    `message_id` ,
    `user_id_2` ,
    `read` ,
    `thread_id`
    )
    VALUES (
    NULL , ?, ?, ?, ?
    );
");

//now insert the message into the user_messages table so the user can be notified of a new message
while ($row = $stmt2->fetch()){
    $stmt3->bind_param("iiii", $inserted_id, $user_2_id, $read, $this->thread_id_clean );
    $stmt3->execute();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried putting the prepared statement inside the loop too, but I keep on getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

I've also ran the query manually with test data, so I know it's the loop that's causing the value not to bind correctly.

Edit: I should add that the select query is working fine and that it's the insert query that is causing an error.

Comment: You mean `SELECT` works and `INSERT` does not work?

Comment: Yeah. I just can't figure out how to bind the $user_2_id variable from the previous query. I've also tried printing out each value that I'm binding to the query, and all results are as expected.

Comment: Hardly ever use `mysqli_`, but `mysqli_error()` might tell you something. However, you know [you can just do this in 1 query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html)? `INSERT INTO uc_user_messages SELECT DISTINCT NULL, ?, user_id, ?, ? FROM uc_user_messages WHERE ....`

Comment: `Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object` leads me to think that the `prepare` is failing for `$stmt3`.

Answer (score 0):

once a var has been bound to your prep statement, it stays bound.

That means that cou call bind_param only once (outside of the loop), and then just repeat the two-step-loop "change var values / execute".

[php.net: Check section #3 INSERT prepared once, executed multiple times](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Also be sure that the quotes you used for db and table names don't interfere with PHPs [backtick operator.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) (In that specific case, you can ommit those quotes.)

Answer (score 0):

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

This means that $stmt2 or $stmt3 is not an object.  The prepare() function returns `false` if there was any problem parsing or validating the query.  But `false->bind_param()` is just not going to work.

This is a very common mistake made by many MySQL developers.  The solution is you have to check that prepare() returned success and not `false`.

Example:

```
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("...");
if ($stmt2 === false) {
  // do something to report $mysqli->error, and return
}
```

Also see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not checking for the errors. Do it the way explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15447204/285587
2. Most likely the error is something like "Commands out of sync" one. You have to use `store_result()` on the first query to avoid that. Strangely, Bill has a [perfect answer which is first on google search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3632320/285587) - you can refer to it for the details.

I only can't get which arrays you are talking about.